# How to change the mapping between program name and executable?

Tags: command-line

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and when I type vim on terminal, it uses the one in `/usr/local/bin`. But I want to use the one in `/usr/bin` instead.

Now, I know that one can achieve this by appending `/usr/bin` in front of PATH.
However, this affects other programs, which is not something I want.

Comment: Is this on Illumos?  Or NetBSD?  Or OpenSUSE?  There are potentially different answers on different operating systems, so you need to _state the operating system in the question_.

Answer (score 3):

You could add an alias for `vim` with

```
alias vim=/usr/bin/vim
```

You could add a shell function for `vim` with

```
vim () { /usr/bin/vim "$@"; }
```

You would add either of these, but not both, to the file that your shell runs for initializing interactive shells (`~/.bashrc` if using `bash`, check your shell's manual).

To just change the hashed location of `vim` in the current shell temporarily, use

```
hash vim=/usr/bin/vim
```

at your interactive prompt (or one of the first two alternatives for that matter).

Comment: Psst!  I didn't mention OpenSUSE idly.  You've overlooked the alternatives system, which exists on Ubuntu as well and which throws up consideration of what `/usr/bin/vim` actually is on such systems and what the VIM programs are actually named.  I said that it was necessary to state the operating system in the question.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP Since neither shell nor OS was mentioned in the question when I first wrote the answer, I made it as generic as I could.  Since I'm not really a Linux user, I will not mention the alternatives system (as I simply don't use it). If it would be easier to use the alternatives system on Ubuntu, then feel free to suggest an edit, or post your own answer. It strikes me now that this Q likely has a few duplicates already.

Comment: Perhaps you should have waited for the operating system to be stated.  (-:  It's not a question of _choosing_ to use the alternatives system.  If one installs one (or more) of the VIM packages (there being several) one _gets_ the alternatives system, and `/usr/bin/vim` is not actually the name of the VIM programs, meaning "the one in `/usr/bin`" in the question actually means something else.

Comment: @JdeBP Does the alternatives system on Ubuntu allow a _user_ (non-root) to pick an alternative `vim`? If so, this could warrant a separate answer.